# why are we allowed to disregard the negative solution when finding the limit of a sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was reading examples of finding limits of sequences from [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~romik/teaching-pages/mat25-hw7solns.pdf), and in question2, they did $\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n^2 = 3 + \lim_{x\to \infty} x_{n-1}$ iff $L^2 = 3+L$. And $L = \frac{1+\sqrt13}{2}$ or $L = \frac{1-\sqrt13}{2}$. They then disregarded the negative solution, so $L = \frac{1+\sqrt13}{2}$. Why are we allowed to disregard the negative solution here?

Comment: Your link leads to nowhere

Comment: I get a "Not Found" error at the link you gave.

Comment: Your link doesn't work.  But if you are looking at the recursion $x_n=\sqrt {3+x_{n-1}}$ then we must have all positive terms (after the first, anyway) so the limit couldn't be negative.   In any case, one would still need to prove that a limit existed.

Comment: Delete here at the end of the link:)

Answer (score 3):

Once you obtain the *necessary* conditions that $L^2=L+3$ where $L$ is the limit, there are in principle three possibilities that remain:

- The sqeuence converges to $L=\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}2$
- The sequence converges to $L=\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}2$
- The sequence does not converge at all.

The third possibility is rules out because the sequence is increasing and bounded, hence certainly convergent.
The second possibility is rules out because every single term of the sequence is positive; hence the limit cannot be negative. (In fact the limit of an increasing sequence, if it exists, is at least as big as any of the terms of the sequence).
As only one of the three possibilities remains, we find that it must be true.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if a recursive equation and fully specified starting conditions are given, then the limit (if it exists) is unique. So you **must** disregard all but one solution, if in the course of your calculations several solutions show up.

In this case, the second solution is negative, but consecutively taking roots of a positive number will produce positive numbers only. So the negative solution must be disregarded.